# Duplicate file Copied

Tags: android, build

I am using Android Studio To develop one app and I need to call rest api. I did all the step to add required jar's in build.gradle. When I rebuild the project it seems fine. But when I tried to run it in emulator it shows below error. I tried almost all the solution available with exclude and all but not solved my problem.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.ForcedAutoDiscoverable
>       File1: C:\Users\everstek 1.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.core\jersey-server\2.22.1\20eee7b976e7005a40f05c0965dd76a308689e98\jersey-server-2.22.1.jar
>       File2: C:\Users\everstek 1.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jersey.media\jersey-media-jaxb\2.22.1\1bc910febfe9e07f741920ff5ac24bb8a59f649f\jersey-media-jaxb-2.22.1.jar

Any one can help. Thanks in advance.

> This are the entries in my build.gradle
>   //compile files('src/main/libs/guava-18.0.jar')
>       compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'

```
//compile files('src/main/libs/hk2-api-2.4.0-b31.jar')
compile 'org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.4.0-b31'

//compile files('src/main/libs/hk2-locator-2.4.0-b31.jar')
compile 'org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.4.0-b31'

//compile files('src/main/libs/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b31.jar')
compile 'org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:2.4.0-b31'

//compile files('src/main/libs/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar')
compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'

//compile files('src/main/libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

//compile files('src/main/libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar')
compile 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1'

//compile files('src/main/libs/jersey-apache-connector-2.22.1.jar')
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-apache-connector:2.22.1'

//compile files('src/main/libs/jersey-client-2.22.1.jar')
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.22.1'

//compile files('src/main/libs/jersey-common-2.22.1.jar')
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.22.1'

//compile files('src/main/libs/jersey-guava-2.22.1.jar')
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:2.22.1'

//compile files('src/main/libs/jersey-media-multipart-2.22.1.jar');
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:2.22.1'

//compile files('src/main/libs/jersey-server-2.22.1.jar')
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.22.1'

//compile files('src/main/libs/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar')
compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'

//compile files('src/main/libs/logback-core-1.1.3.jar')
compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'

//compile files('src/main/libs/mimepull-1.9.6.jar');
compile 'org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:1.9.6'

//compile files('src/main/libs/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar')
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.12'
```

Comment: May we see your build.gradle?

Comment: I got the solution. We have to keep only one among jersey-server or jersey-media-multipart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This Solution I Got Shows Some Warnings But Works Fine**

```
We have to add dependency in group manner that will help us to understood better. For My Above Question I Have To Add This In Dependency


compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '19.0'
//compile files('libs/guava-18.0.jar')
compile group: 'org.glassfish.hk2', name: 'hk2-api', version: '2.5.0-b06'
//compile files('libs/hk2-api-2.4.0-b31.jar')
compile group: 'org.glassfish.hk2', name: 'hk2-locator', version: '2.5.0-b06'
//compile files('libs/hk2-locator-2.4.0-b31.jar')
compile group: 'org.glassfish.hk2', name: 'hk2-utils', version: '2.5.0-b06'
//compile files('libs/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b31.jar')
compile group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: '1.2'
//compile files('libs/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar')
compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'
//compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
compile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.0.1'
//compile files('libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar')
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.connectors', name: 'jersey-apache-connector', version: '2.23.1'
//compile files('libs/jersey-apache-connector-2.22.1.jar')
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-client', version: '2.23.1'
//compile files('libs/jersey-client-2.22.1.jar')
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-common', version: '2.23.1'
//compile files('libs/jersey-common-2.22.1.jar')
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged', name: 'jersey-guava', version: '2.23.1'
//compile files('libs/jersey-guava-2.22.1.jar')
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-multipart', version: '2.23.1'
//compile files('libs/jersey-media-multipart-2.22.1.jar')
//compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-server', version: '2.23.1'
//compile files('libs/jersey-server-2.22.1.jar')
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.1.7'
//compile files('libs/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar')
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.1.7'
//compile files('libs/logback-core-1.1.3.jar')
compile group: 'org.jvnet.mimepull', name: 'mimepull', version: '1.9.6'
//compile files('libs/mimepull-1.9.6.jar')
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.21'
```

Answer (score 0):

jersey-guava and jersey-common are included in the jersey-client dependency. You don't need to add each individual one. Also, the server dependency is unnecessary for the Android app if the app is a client.

Try cleaning your project, but it looks like you're using the jersey-server repo.

Remove your current jersey dependency, run the 'clean' gradle task, and add this dependency:

```
dependencies {
   //other dependencies
   compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.22.2'
}
```

If you would rather use jersey 2.22.1 just change the version number in the dependency.

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/jersey_2_x_client_on1
you may also have to use this workaround to make sure you only use packages android supports

Comment: Try removing compile ...jersey-common

Comment: When I add .jar files in lib's folder it works fine, but when I add it in build with compile '----' it doesn't work. Gives exception as I shown above at run time

Comment: Try removing every dependency except Jersey client and your Jersey jax-rs unrelated dependencies.

Comment: I got the solution. We have to keep only one among jersey-server or jersey-media-multipart